# Should I release client in Knex.js?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm using PostgreSQL with `pg`. Configuration is as follows:

```
const { Pool } = require("pg");
const { dbUser, dbHost, database, dbHmac, dbPort } = require("../config");

const dbConfig = {
  user: dbUser,
  host: dbHost,
  database,
  password: dbHmac,
  port: dbPort,
  max: 10,
  idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
 };

 var pool = new Pool(dbConfig);
 module.exports = pool;
```

At present the pool is used as follows:

```
app.post("/deleteCognitoUserBasedOnEmail", async function (req, res) {
let isUserAdminRes, email = req.body.email;
try {
   isUserAdminRes = await client.query(
   `select is_admin from end_user where email = $1`,[email]
   );
}
catch (e) {
  client.release();
  console.error("Error occurred : " + e);
  return res.status(500).send({ errorMessage: "Internal Server Error. " + e.message });
}
client.release();
return res
  .status(status)
  .send({ responseMessage });
 }
```

As one can see I have to release the client everywhere. There are complex functions in my project which take and pass the client as an argument. This way at times tracking client became difficult. I decided to switch to knex.js.
Is there any such restriction in Knex.js? I read about the .destroy() method in knex.js but it is to be used when you won't need the connection. But in my project, the APIs will be hit multiple times throughout the day, every day.

Comment: No, knex.js manages the pool for you - it borrows a client for a query and releases it automatically. You only have to make sure that you resolve your Promises if you're using transactions.

Comment: @RobertKawecki Thanks for the reply. Can you refer me to the official document where it states the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of knex.js, the numerous examples all omit connection management; it is non-existent in user code. It's just not mentioned in the docs, because you don't do it. Thus, it's *documented by absence*.

If you prefer hard evidence, here's the code that actually executes queries in knex.js - note how `ensureConnection` sets up a connection before and releases it after the queries: https://github.com/knex/knex/blob/8cfad286f246aff7455784b51751fdd17ba24c4c/lib/execution/runner.js#L27

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I was worried to use knex because I could not find anything in regards to the client handling. Now that you cleared it up, I feel confident  to actually use knex!